# Managed metadata column - adding new terms directly

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, enterprise-keywords

I have an Enterprise Keywords column in a list, added via the "Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings" screen. When a user types a new keyword for this column, it is saved to the System > Keywords term set.

Now I want to have a keywords column which uses a different term set. I can add a Managed Metadata type column, and select a term set for it to use. But when the user enters a new keyword and presses Save, the message "The given term is not valid" is displayed. It's possible to click the button next to the field to browse the existing terms and add a new item, but this interface is much more complicated than simply entering the new keyword.

Is it possible to either:

- make the Enterprise Keywords column use a term set other than System > Keywords, or
- have the Managed Metadata column allow new terms to be added without needing to use the term browsing dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Turning the term store's Submission Policy to "Open" through the Term Store Management Tool (on the General tab) would enable you to accomplish what you're trying.

Comment: This appears to work for site collection term sets; I've tried the same with term sets in the a System group and it will act as described in the original question.